# iphone - Display modal view(slideup) in a tab bar interface with navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, modal-dialog

I am new to iphone programming and any help would be nice. I have an application with 3 tabs with the last one going deep, hence created a view based application with tab bar as the root controller and added navigation controller using this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW2).

In my 2nd tab which is a subclass of UIViewController, I am trying to display a modal view, also being a subclass of UIViewController. In my 2nd tab, when I try to present the modal view, the app crashed and says 'GDB: Program recieved signal:"SIGABRT"'. This is what I have

```
ModalViewController *mvc = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:mvc animated:YES];
```

Here 'self' is the 2nd Tab's UIViewController. How to present the modal which is a view controller in the 2nd tab? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ModalViewController *mvc = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalView" bundle:nil];
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:mvc animated:YES];
[mvc release];
```

There was memory leak, you must release the object after use **[mvc release];**

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried this, but I get "tabBarController" undefined. I dont have it in my scope. In my appdelegate I add my tab bar and navbar controllers. So I got my delegate and tried to access tabcontroller like this, but still its crashing.`[delegate.myTabController presentModalViewController: mvc animated:YES];`

Comment: Of course it is undefined in your current controller. Did you synthesize the property "myTabController" in your app delegate? In your current controller, how are you accessing your application delegate? You should access it something like:  `appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

Comment: Did you create an IBOutlet of your myTabController and make the property? show us your delegate class file and how you are creating the myTabController? are using xib file or programmatically?

Comment: In my app delegate, I have my tabcontoller.    `@interface TabNavAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;  IBOutlet UITabBarController *myTabController;
} @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *myTabController;` In my current controller, i say        `TabNavAppDelegate *delegate = (TabNavAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;[delegate.myTabController presentModalViewController:mvc animated:YES];[mvc release];`

Comment: I followed this [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw] to create my tab bar and nav bar

Comment: I think the problem is in the nib file. Becoz if I create my modal view controller without the nib file, the app doesn't crash and I see the slide up view. I am missing something in my modal view nib file. Can anyone suggest a tutorial for modal view connections and also the slide up view not hiding the tab bar.

Comment: @Deeksha First fix your nib file, check is there any warning into your nib file?

Comment: I deleted my nib file and created it again and made my File Owner connection to view and set the File Owner's class to the Modal Controller and it worked. Sometimes just deleting and doing again helps. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Deeksha i knew it since before that your nib file is not correect

Answer (score 0):

ModalViewController needs to be a child of the TabBarController:

```
ModalViewController *mvc = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalView" bundle:nil];
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:newNavController
                                                       animated:YES];
```

Comment: The answer what Maggie has given a bit hacky to me UINavigationController does not allow UITabBarControllers to be pushed onto its navigation stack. The tab bar widget itself can be included on navigation screens, and so one approach is to use the navigation-based application template.

Comment: yes, sorry, I just read the code part and assumed there was a problem with presenting modal view controller. will edit my answer.